# Selenium webdriver not able to indentify the element when used in a function

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to login to gmail using function. I am passing user name from an excel sheet. Problem is my code return the value but not entering in the text box. It is not throwing any error just returning the null exception.

Please help me with this, i am new to selenium webdriver and really have no idea what to do next as its not showing any error as well.

```
public class gmail 
 {

public static WebDriver driver;

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
    File file1 = new      File("C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file1.getAbsolutePath());
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("www.gmail.com");    



      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Automation\\Selenium\\New Folder\\Demo\\Book2.xls"));   // Path of the excel where the keywords and data was mentioned
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);    
      HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      int d= sheet.getLastRowNum();
      System.out.println(d);   


     for (int i=1;i<=d;i++)
      {
           Cell cell1=null;
            cell1=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0);
            System.out.println(cell1);

            if (cell1.getStringCellValue().contains("text"))      
            {
                  Cell cell2=null;
                  cell2=sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1);
                  System.out.println(cell2);
                  stg(cell2);   //calling function                 

            }    

      }     

}  

public static void stg(Cell cell2) throws InterruptedException 
{
  WebElement un1=driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));
  System.out.println(un1);
  un1.sendKeys(cell2.getStringCellValue());

 }
```

}

```
 //This is the Output which i am getting:
 1
text
```

seltest10j

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Excel.gmail.stg(gmail.java:63)
at Excel.gmail.main(gmail.java:53)
```

Comment: You have a null variable at line 63 on file gmail.java and trying to access some method/field. This is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Line 63 in my code is: WebElement un1=driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));   I don't know why it is returning null value. when i use the same code out side the function then it is returning proper value. Please suggest me what else i can do in this. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you're not initalizing the class field `driver`:

`public static WebDriver driver;`

At the same time, you declare a local variable **with the same name** inside the `main` method:

`WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

Was the code in the `stg` method inside `main` when the code was working? That would work because the local variable is actually initialized. When you move the code outside main, the local variable no longer hides the class field and since you don't initialize it you get a NullPointerException.

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) to learn more about fields and local variables, and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) to learn about hiding fields.

Comment: Thank you so much orique. It worked after initializing the class field driver. Thank you so much for your help. It is working fine now.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you upvote and/or accept the answer? For other users it will help to find a solution for a similiar problem and we will rise a bit our rep :)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend NOT to automate Gmail using Selenium. Its highly complicated and you should rather focus on automating your OWN application than gmail. Use gmail POP3 server to retrieve emails etc. Here is my answer on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868183/webdriver-to-open-a-mail-in-gmail).